# Find egrep regex for a sentence specific length

Tags: linux, grep

I need an egrep expression that matches exactly five word sentences.  The sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with a punctuation mark.  I need to use `:alpha:`, `:upper:` and `:punct:` classes.

I have:

```
[[:upper:]][a-z]* [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+[[:punct:]]
```

but this also finds sentences that have a name in it and then the more words, for example

```
My friend Frank ate a big sandwich.
```

I can't use `-w` either.

Comment: Your description is unclear.  Please give examples that the incorrectly matches.

Comment: My friend Frank ate a big sandwich.

Comment: use `[[:lower:]]` rather than `[[:alpha:]]`.  Also `[a-z]` should be `[[:lower:]]`.

Comment: but it won't match I like the Cubs.

Comment: Actually, for "I like the Cubs":  1) 4 words not 5, and 2) "Cubs" is a name.  Either mean that it shouldn't match ... according to your specification.

Comment: Also "This FYI should not match." ... because "FYI" is not a name.  Seriously, distinguishing names from other things based solely on capitalization is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you anchor your solution as follows, it won't match your example sentence from the comments any longer:

```
grep -E '^[[:upper:]][a-z]* [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+ [[:alpha:]]+[[:punct:]]$'
```

You can make this a little shorter, as there is a repeating pattern:

```
grep -E '^[[:upper:]][a-z]*( [[:alpha:]]+){4}[[:punct:]]$'
```